# How to generate a plane that fills a wall?

Tags: realitykit, visionos

I have a wall anchor that I would like to place a plane on. It's working fine, but I have to give an explicit size. I'd like the plane to be the size of the wall. Any way to accomplish this?

```
@State var wallEntity: Entity = {
        let minumumBounds = SIMD2<Float>(0.6, 0.6) // 60cm x 60cm
        let wallAnchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.vertical, classification: .wall, minimumBounds: minumumBounds))
        let planeMesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 6, depth: 2.625, cornerRadius: 0.1)
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1), isMetallic: false)
        let planeEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: planeMesh, materials: [material])
        planeEntity.name = "wall"
        wallAnchor.addChild(planeEntity)
        return wallAnchor
}()
```